# Fun with Java generics

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Anybody knows how to write the piece of code below using generics AND avoiding compiler warnings ? (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is considered cheating).

And, maybe, checking via generics that the type of "left" is the same as the type of "right" ?

```
public void assertLessOrEqual(Comparable left, Comparable right) {
    if (left == null || right == null || (left.compareTo(right) > 0)) {
        String msg = "["+left+"] is not less than ["+right+"]";
        throw new RuntimeException("assertLessOrEqual: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works with subclasses of Comparable types too:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void assertLessOrEqual(T left, T right) {
  if (left == null || right == null || left.compareTo(right) > 0) {
    String msg = "["+left+"] is not less than ["+right+"]";
    throw new RuntimeException("assertLessOrEqual: " + msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the sort of extra complication I was thinking of, yes :)

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void assertLessOrEqual(T left, T right) {
  if (left == null || right == null || (left.compareTo(right) > 0)) {
    String msg = "["+left+"] is not less than ["+right+"]";
    throw new RuntimeException("assertLessOrEqual: " + msg);
  }
}
```

It could probably be made a *little* bit more general, but only by making it more complicated as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot via generics check if the type of 'left' is the same as the type of 'right' at runtime. Java generics is implemented via [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so that the information about the generic type parameters is lost at runtime.

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void assertLessOrEqual(T left, T right) {
    if (left == null || right == null || (left.compareTo(right) > 0)) {
        String msg = "["+left+"] is not less than ["+right+"]";
        throw new RuntimeException("assertLessOrEqual: " + msg);
    }
}
```