# How to implement a generic `max(Comparable a, Comparable b)` function in Java?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm trying to write a generic max function that takes two `Comparable`s.

So far I have

```
public static <T extends Comparable<?>> T max(T a, T b) {
    if (a == null) {
        if (b == null) return a;
        else return b;
    }
    if (b == null)
        return a;
    return a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

This fails to compiles with

```
The method compareTo(capture#5-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#5-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

What I think this is saying is that that the `?` in `Comparable<?>` may be interpreted as one type for parameter a, and another for parameter b, so that they can't be compared.

How do I dig myself out of this hole?

Comment: In the `if(a==null)` block, there is no need for the nested if clause. Reducing the block to `return b;` yields the same result (`null` when `b` is `null`, `b` otherwise).

Comment: See [org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.compare](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#compare-T-T-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For best results you should use `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T a, T b)`.

The problem with `<T extends Comparable<?>>` is that this says that the type T is comparable to some type, but you don't know what that type is. Of course, common sense would dictate that a class which implements Comparable should be able to be comparable to at least itself (i.e. be able to compare to objects of its own type), but there is technically nothing preventing class A from implementing `Comparable<B>`, where A and B have nothing to do with each other. `<T extends Comparable<T>>` solves this problem.

But there's a subtle problem with that. Suppose class X implements `Comparable<X>`, and I have a class Y that extends X. So class Y automatically implements `Comparable<X>` by inheritance. Class Y can't also implement `Comparable<Y>` because a class cannot implement an interface twice with different type parameters. This is not really a problem, since instances of Y are instances of X, so Y is comparable to all instances of Y. But the problem is that you cannot use the type Y with your `<T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b)` function, because Y doesn't implement `Comparable<Y>`. The bounds are too strict. `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` fixes the problem, because it is sufficient for T to be comparable to some supertype of T (which would include all T instances). Recall the rule PECS - producer `extends`, consumer `super` - in this case, `Comparable` is a consumer (it takes in an object to compare against), so `super` makes sense.

This is the type bounds used by all of the sorting and ordering functions in the Java library.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because `Comparable<?>` basically says that it is comparable to something without any specifics. You should write `Comparable<T>` instead, so the compiler would know that type T is comparable to itself.

Comment: Thanks - now to solve the real problem, which was to port it to Scala!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question from SO's generated related links - this seems to be a subtle duplicate of [Fun with Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1438028/97777) , although I guess you can't blame me for not finding it given the title!

The simplest solution seems to be

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    if (a == null) {
        if (b == null) return a;
        else return b;
    }
    if (b == null)
        return a;
    return a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a utility class for this. Maybe you find it useful (the library is Open Source):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Comparables.html

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupid>org.softsmithy.lib</groupid>  
    <artifactid>lib-core</artifactid>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. This is the sort of thing that I'm gobsmacked isn't part of the standard library, given how much code it takes and how easy it is to get wrong.

Comment: Note: I just checked the source code: it doesn't support null values currently: http://softsmithy.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/softsmithy/lib/main-golden/file/5c4db802573b/lib-core/src/main/java/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Comparables.java

Comment: :-) Thanks for coming clean - I'm sure mine wouldn't have had I not been dealing with a domain where lots of dates might not have been supplied.

Answer (score 1):

It's offten better getting already implemented iso create owns. See at [Min / Max function with two Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265954/min-max-function-with-two-comparable). Simplest is `org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils`:

```
Comparable<C> a = ...;
Comparable<C> b = ...;
Comparable<C> min = ObjectUtils.min(a, b);
```