# In convertible cast, casting from T to double

Tags: java, generics

I want to create generic method for getting maximal value from the array. However I got stuck at the problem of conversion between T to type Math.max method uses.

here is my code:
First I cannot initialize the maxValue like:

```
T maxVaue = 0;
```

secondly I cannot use data[i] in Math.max, in both cases I got error of In convertible cast.

```
class Matrix<T>{
    public T getMaxValue(T[] data){
        T maxValue;
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            maxValue = Math.max(data[i], maxValue);
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.max takes only int, float, double and long. So you can not use it with `T`.

What you can do is write your own max() method using T. For example, your method could take a `Comparator` object in param. Or your T objects can implement the `Comparable` interface.

Have a look at this post : [How to implement a generic `max(Comparable a, Comparable b)` function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452313/how-to-implement-a-generic-maxcomparable-a-comparable-b-function-in-java)

Comment: I agree, `Comparable` is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that as you are doing it because a `T` can be anything. You could e.g. limit `T` to a `Number` but then you'd have to choose an intermediate primitive type and you will still run into issues returning the value.

However, you could just limit `T` to `Comparable` and use that instead, e.g.:

```
class Matrix<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    public T getMaxValue(T[] data){
        T maxValue = null;
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if (maxValue == null || data[i].compareTo(maxValue) > 0)
                maxValue = data[i];
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

All of Java's primitive wrapper types implement `Comparable`, as well as many other types:

```
byte by = new Matrix<Byte>().getMaxValue(new Byte[]{1, 2, 3});
char ch = new Matrix<Character>().getMaxValue(new Character[]{'a', 'b', 'c'});
int in = new Matrix<Integer>().getMaxValue(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
short sh = new Matrix<Short>().getMaxValue(new Short[]{1, 2, 3});
long lo = new Matrix<Long>().getMaxValue(new Long[]{1L, 2L, 3L});
float fl = new Matrix<Float>().getMaxValue(new Float[]{0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f});
double db = new Matrix<Double>().getMaxValue(new Double[]{0.1, 0.2, 0.3});
boolean bo = new Matrix<Boolean>().getMaxValue(new Boolean[]{false, true});
String st = new Matrix<String>().getMaxValue(new String[]{"turtles", "are", "weird"});
BigInteger bi = new Matrix<BigInteger>().getMaxValue(new BigInteger[]{...});
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` can hold only classes like `Double`, `Integer`, not primitive types like `double`, `int`. Maybe just use built-in `Collections.max(Collection<T extends Comparable<T>>)` and array of `Doubles` instead of `doubles` like in this code example

```
class Matrix<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T getMaxValue(T[] data) {
        return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(data));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Matrix<Double> m = new Matrix<>();
        System.out.println(m.getMaxValue(new Double[] { 1., 42., 3., 4., 5. }));
    }
}
```