# Min / max function of two Comparables

Tags: java, comparable

I need to find the smaller of two `Comparable` values:

```
Comparable<C> a = ...;
Comparable<C> b = ...;
Comparable<C> min = a.compareTo(b) <= 0 ? a : b;
```

This is similar to `Math.min(a, b)`, but for `Comparable`.

I know that the ternary operator is already quite short, but I can't inline the expressions for `a` and `b` and I think that `min(a, b)` and `max(a, b)` is easier to understand.

I know that there are several functions that operate on `Stream` and `Collection` values, like:

```
Stream.of(a, b).min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

This would help to inline the expressions, but I still find it difficult to read and a bit too much overhead for such a small task.

For the moment I'm using my own utility function, but I'm interested to know if there's an existing function for this purpose.  How can one find the minimum of two `Comparable` values in a readable and library-independent manner without too much performance overhead?

Comment: [`ObjectUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html) has this.

Comment: Guava has one, but recommends another (more verbose) alternative for Java 8: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#min-E-E-

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I changed the question from "Is there" to "How to", which will lead to the same answers but hopefully prevent such flags...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. From `java.util.Collections`:  [***`Collections.max()`***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) and [***`Collections.min()`***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-)

   ```
   Comparable<C> a = ...;
   Comparable<C> b = ...;
   Comparable<C> min = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(a,b));
   ```

---

2. From `org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils` : [***`ObjectUtils.max()`***](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#max(java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable)) and [***`ObjectUtils.min()`***](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#min(java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable))

   ```
   Comparable<C> a = ...;
   Comparable<C> b = ...;
   Comparable<C> min = ObjectUtils.min(a, b);
   ```

Apache Commons has less overhead and is able to handle `null` values, but it is a third party library.

Answer (score 8):

I have created my own helper class, which extends `Comparable` by `min`, `max`, `isLessThan`, `isLessOrEqualTo`, `isGreaterThan` and `isGreaterOrEqualTo`:

```
public interface Ordered<T> extends Comparable<T> {

  static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) <= 0 ? a : b;
  }

  static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) >= 0 ? a : b;
  }

  default boolean isLessThan(T other) {
    return compareTo(other) < 0;
  }

  default boolean isLessOrEqualTo(T other) {
    return compareTo(other) <= 0;
  }

  default boolean isGreaterThan(T other) {
    return compareTo(other) > 0;
  }

  default boolean isGreaterOrEqualTo(T other) {
    return compareTo(other) >= 0;
  }

}
```

The `min` and `max` methods I use for any Comparable:

```
String first = "a";
String second = "b";
System.out.println(Ordered.min(first, second)); // Prints "a"
```

For my own implementations of `Comparable` I extend `Ordered` and use that one for readable comparisons. Very helpful for enums:

```
public enum Board implements Ordered<Board> {
  NONE,
  BREAKFAST,
  HALF_BOARD,
  FULL_BOARD,
  ALL_INCLUSIVE
}
```

Usage:

```
Board requestedBoard = ...;
Board availableBoard = ...;
if (requestedBoard.isLessOrEqualTo(availableBoard)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nice helper class! To handle more cases (e.g. `LocalDateTime result = max(a, b)`), generics can be written this way: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: That's right, I adapted my answer.

Answer (score 7):

### 3<sup>rd</sup> party solutions

`Collections` has `max(collection)` and `min(collection)` methods, which kind of do what you want.

Bringing whole new library just to inline one simple op might be an overkill, unless you have **Apache Commons** or **Guava** in the mix.

### Hand crafted

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b) { 
    return a.compareTo(b) >= 0 ? a : b; 
}

public <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(T a, T b) { 
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library has the [`Comparators.min`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#min(T,T)) and [`Comparators.max`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#max(T,T)) methods as of version 30.0:

```java
Comparable<C> min = Comparators.min(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `Stream`

```
Comparable<C> min = Stream.of(a, b).min(Comparable::compareTo).get();
```

Note that you will usually not call `get()` and assign, but use `ifPresent(min -> ...)` instead.  But in this case you can trust the value to be present since the stream is not empty.

Comment: Did you see that I already mentioned that option in my question?

Comment: Ahh no I should have read it completely.   Still, I think it's the best library independent option if you don't create your own function.